# How to use cronJob in PHP

Tags: php, cron

I want to schedule some tasks according to some time limitation for example unassigned a task if user did not submit in 24 hours.

Comment: Whats the problem with using a cron job?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is 24hrs ON, then you can write your code in single page and include in the common page which is accessed everytime. e.g. we do it in includefile.php which is accessed every time when we open a site in browser.

But for this your site must be always being browsed by people, That time your code will run. And you need to put time limit,always need to set flags once the task is executed.

Comment: is it possible that to run code without site browsed by people?

Comment: No.. Then only the way to set a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cronjob and use as command a php script:

```
*/5 * * * * php -f /path/to/script.php
```